# Will auto-pagination work in Cassandra without providing the limit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, cql, cql3

After reading doc(driver doc) and few answers, it seems that Cassandra 2.0+ has an auto paging. But all such examples included `LIMIT` keyword.

Does this query applicable in auto-paging:

```
current_version_query = "SELECT id, row_hash FROM {} WHERE version={}".format(
            self.table_name, self.diff_source_version
        )
        current_version_rows = self.session.execute(
            current_version_query
        )
```

I am iterating over it here:
`for current_version_row in current_version_rows:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two limits, a fetch size and a total request limit (`LIMIT` clause). When you make any request there is a default 5000 fetch limit and max_int query limit.

The driver will by default page in 5000 row batches until it reaches the query limit or the end of the results. It is often a good idea to lower this if your rows are large to reduce load on the coordinator from building MBs of response payloads.

Comment: Just to be on same page:
As per my current code, it will auto paginate, right?

Comment: yes but if you have less than 5000 entries it will return everything in one fetch anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir!